# Validation of viewstate MAC failed when Cookies are Disabled on Client Browser

Tags: asp.net

I have tried specifying the machineKey, etc, to no availability. The site crashes when I have a form and my users have the cookies disabled on their browser.

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot
>   be used in a cluster.

This is not on a cluster.

Comment: Crashes the entire website?  Lol.  Try catching where it is crashing.  Then, if the user has their cookies turned off, spurn them as the phoenicians spurned brown goats.

Comment: yes, lol, it crashes at the framework level, lol "Validation of viewstate MAC failed"

Comment: Prior to **any** of your code being called?  Velly eentelesting.  You sure it's cookie related?  Docs here don't mention cookies https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: The only way that I can cause the crash is disabling the cookies on the browser, it fails spectacularly

Comment: Any inner exceptions or exception details along with the failure?  Sometimes it includes details to the end of the default message, such as "cannot autocreate in cluster" or stuff like that...

Comment: Will, I'm guessing that submitting a form and having cookies disabled is just not supported in ASP.NET due to cross-site scripting concerns and such.. so the answer might just be to disable the form if cookies are not enabled, what do you think?

Comment: I don't know, unfortunately.  There *has* to be a way to handle this better when the user disables cookies.  I just can't tell you what that answer is :/

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but in case it helps others if the .NET web app has ViewStateUserKey enabled and is using session id as part of the user key, then if session cookies are disabled the user key will not be known, causing the viewstate MAC validation failure.